# Cannot run debug in VsCode. Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb, lib, .so

Im trying run program in debug.
The program is compiled with cmake conan.
My config vscode:

```
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/bin/program",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }


{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Error:

```
/home/user/git_repos/program/build/bin/program: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-mezeyszy.sh4" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-nbctgvn3.1sn"
```

I have all of this files, how i can show path to it for vscode? Or if this does not help solve the problem, then what are the ways and what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: What are your relevant `RPATH` and `LD_PRELOAD` values?